# Cone volume using triple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

The cone is defined by $ \{(x,y,z) : \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq 2\}$. How can I calculate the area using triple integrals?

Answer (score 2):

Polar coordinates. $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ goes up to $z$.

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\tau=2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_0^z r \ \ \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{4}{3}\tau$